# Dump map<string, string> to char vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a map that I want to dump into a char array.
The array is supposed to look like this:

```
key1=value\0key2=value2\0key3=value3\0\0
```

Each `map` key shall be followed by `'='`, the value and a terminating `NUL` character.

My approach produces garbage:

```
char* pChar = &data[0];
std::vector<char> writable;
string key;
string value;

for (std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator iter = myMap.begin(); iter != myMap.end(); iter++)
{
    writable.resize( iter->first.size()  + iter->second.size() + 2);
    key = iter->first;
    value = iter->second;
    memcpy(&writable[0], &key, key.length());
    std::fill(writable.begin() +  key.length(), writable.begin() +  key.length(), 0x3D );
    memcpy(&writable[key.length() + 1], &value,  value.length());
    std::fill(writable.begin() +  key.length() + value.length() + 1, writable.begin() + key.length() + value.length() + 1, 0x0 );
    memcpy(pChar, &writable[0], writable.size());
    pChar += writable.size();
}
memset(pChar, 0, 1);
```

Comment: why `vector<char>` and not `string` ? memcpy and memset are not needed here.

Comment: Thanks, that actually makes more sense. Just concatenating the string, then taking the `c_str()` which already has a terminating NUL and copy it to `pChar`

Answer (score 2):

The standard char sequence container is `std::string`, your code can be reduced to :

```
int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m = { 
        { "k0" , "v0" } ,
        { "k1" , "v1" },
        { "k2" , "v2" }, 
        { "k3" , "v3" } 
    };

    std::string result;

    for(auto& pair : m)
        result += pair.first + "=" + pair.second + " ";

    std::cout << result;
}
```

And you can easily get a `std::vector<char>` from a `string` if you really need it :

```
std::vector<char> v(result.begin(), result.end());
```

And you can of course get the underlying c-stye array with the `c_str()` member function.

---

**EDIT:**

If you really want a `std::vector<char>` with NUL character as separators, you can use `std::copy` and a `std::back_inserter` :

```
std::vector<char> result;

for(auto& pair : m)
{
   std::copy(pair.first.begin(), pair.first.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
   std::copy(pair.second.begin(), pair.second.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
   result.push_back('\0');
}
```

Comment: This doesn't use `NUL` (`\0`) characters as OP wishes to.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `memcpy` to copy in from the address of an std::string.  You want to copy in from the contents of the string in `key.c_str()` and `value.c_str()`.